# Javascript await never seems to finish when not wrapped in a second promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, electron

I'm writing a little script using Electron that calls a Python script to take a screenshot of the window along with writing to a textile. I am having an issue where an awaited function is not behaving as intended. I have a wrapper function around the VanillaJS `setTimeout` function to convert it to a promise.

```
function wait(ms) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(resolve, ms);
    });
}
```

This function works fine on its own and I've used it in other programs before without any issues. In this case, I am trying to loop a specified number of times and wait a set time within each loop. This behavior works as intended if I call `wait()` within another promise (and in this case, within an `ipc.once` event). However, if I call it outside of the promise it instead never completes the loop and just freezes.

I cannot seem to figure out why this behavior occurs and I've sent a few hours trying to figure it out, but to no avail.

```
async function takeScreenshot(numPhotos) {
    let stream = fs.createWriteStream("labels.manifest", { flags: "a" });

    for (let i = 0; i < numPhotos; i++) {
        await wait(500);

        await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            // Wait for the front-end script to send the labels
            ipc.once("sendLabels", async (event, data, err) => {
                if (err) reject(err);

                writeManifest(i, stream, data); // Write the manifest file with the given labels
                spawn("python", ["screenshot.py", i.toString()], {
                    cwd: process.cwd(),
                    detached: true,
                    stdio: "inherit",
                }); // Call the python screenshot script
                resolve(); // Resolve the promise
            });
        });
        await win.reload();
    }
}
```

In this code, with the wait outside of the `ipc.once` it will not complete running for whatever reason.

If someone could shed some light on why this is happening, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Do not use a for loop with fake sleep. Make a queue

Comment: @primelf Can you please check if the freezes come from another function, for example `writeManifest()`. I don't think your code is wrong. But if you want to do something after a specific time period, you should you `setInterval()`, async/await in a for loop will block the thread and no other code can be executed.

Comment: @DucNguyen I believe I want the thread to be blocked. When reloading the page with Electron, it doesn't seem to await for it to fully load. To combat this I was trying to wait ~250ms for the page to fully load before continuing. I did try messing around and it doesn't seem like the issue is in any of the other methods. Though I cant seem to get the Python script to print within the Node app despite doing what others recommend online, so I cant be positive. But it does only appear when I shift the wait function.